# ruby code quality checker that could catch debugger statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-metrics

I am looking for a ruby code quality checker that could catch or notify if something like a 'debugger' statement gets accidentally committed to ruby code. It would also be ideal if it could look in a rails project and scan any places that may contain ruby code like a haml file.

The idea would be that this would be run with cruisecontrol.rb and against a code base where there are holes in test coverage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't over-think it! Just write a simple script to search for it over your app's directory.

Using command-line `grep`:

```
grep -r --include='*.rb' debugger .
```

Using [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/):

```
ack --type=ruby debugger
```

Using Ruby's `grep`:

```
Dir['**/*.rb'].each do |path|
  File.open(path, 'r') do |file|
    file.grep /debugger/ do
      puts path
    end
  end
end
```

(Ruby code lovingly adapted from _why's [Wearing Ruby Slippers to Work](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/wearingRubySlippersToWork.html))

You might also want to consider searching over Javascript files for `"debugger"` as well, and possibly `"console.log"`, etc.

You may also want to make this be more strict to reduce false positives by using something like `/^\s*debugger\s*$/` to only match it when it's the only thing on the line. Adapting this to work for HAML probably requires a bit more: `/^\s*[-=]\s*debugger\s*$/`.

Comment: This would work nicely as a pre-commit hook if OP is using Git.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by @Andrew Mashall. For our rails project we use a slightly modified version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

expressions = [/^\s*binding\.pry/, /^\s*debugger/, /^\s*console\.log/, /^\s*save_and_open_page/]                                                                                                                                             
debuggers = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
dirs = `git ls-files |grep '\\(rb\\|haml\\|rake\\|js\\|coffee\\)$'`.split                                                                                                                                                                    
dirs.each do |path|                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File.open(path, 'r') do |file|
    contents = file.read
    expressions.each do |expr|                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      contents.match expr do                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        debuggers << path                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
raise "debugger statements found in #{debuggers.to_s}" unless debuggers.empty?
```

We also added it into our `.git/hooks/pre-commit` script and to our continuous-integration build to double-check we don't leave debug statements around...